# Return only ID in json instead full entity object

Tags: spring

I have a problem with creating response from my RESTful application in Spring Boot. I have entity which contain 2 subentity properties.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "attendances")
public class Attendance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private long version;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_created")
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")
    @NotNull
    private Meeting meeting;

getters, setters..
}
```

When I get JSON with this data, I always get full object with full Member and Meeting entities. In this case, I need only member id and meeting id. Is it possible to do that with a specific annotations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Solution by annotations

It is possible by using the annotation for JSON views `@JsonView`

```
public class View {
    interface Summary {}
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "attendances")
public class Attendance {

    ...

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member member;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")
    @NotNull
    private Meeting meeting;

    ...
}

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public Attendance annotationShowCase() {
        Attendance attendance = // retrieve attendance
        return attendance;
    }
}
```

Because `annotationShowCase()` is annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)`, the returned `Attendance` will only expose the fields also annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)`.

#### Solution by DTO

This solution uses the DTO construct: create a new class which serves the purpose of exposing certain fields to JSON

```
public class AttendanceSummary {

    private long memberId;
    private long meetingId;

    public AttendanceSummary(Attendance attendance) {
        this.memberId = attendance.getMemberId();
        this.meetingId = attendance.getMeetingId();
    }

    // getters and setters
}

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public AttendanceSummary dtoShowCase() {
        Attendance attendance = // retrieve attendance
        return new AttendanceSummary(attendance);
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically only want the 'id' or only one of the entity fields to be returned then, you can use **@JsonIdentityInfo** and **@JsonIdentityReference** annotations to get the job done.

Example:

```
    @Entity
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    class Member {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;
       ....
    }

    @Entity
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    class Meeting {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;
       ....
    }

    @Entity
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @Table(name = "attendances")
    public class Attendance {

        ...

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
        @NotNull
        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        private Member member;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")
        @NotNull
        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        private Meeting meeting;

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Jackson default use getters to creating json. You can use trick. You need to overwrite default getters to return id of object. Also like previous Leroy mentioned you need to create view. You should created two fields with @Transient annotation, that means hibernate not will be mapping these fields to entity and after that set new view on these fields by @JsonView annotation. From now you do not need any additional DTO wraper.

```
 public class View {
    interface Summary {}
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "attendances")
public class Attendance {

    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_id")
    @NotNull
    private Meeting meeting;
    
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @Transient
    private Long memberId;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @Transient
    private Long meetingId

    public Long getMemberId() {
       return member.getId();
    }

    public Long getMeetingId() {
       return meeting.getId();
    }
    ...
}

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public Attendance annotationShowCase() {
        Attendance attendance = // retrieve attendance
        return attendance;
    }
}
```